# I can not move another path in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vue-router

Im new to Vue JS and I'm making a simple page in Vue JS. Here are my codes:

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import PokeProfile from './components/PokeProfile.vue'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(ElementUI)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: '/', component: App},
    {path: '/pokemon/:id', component: PokeProfile},
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})

//Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router: router
})
```

App.js

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="tag-group">
      <el-tag
          v-for="pokemon in pokemons"
          :key="pokemon.national_id"
          :type="pokemon.name"
          effect="plain">
          <poke-item :pokemon=pokemon></poke-item>
        </el-tag>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PokeItem from './components/PokeItem.vue'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    PokeItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pokemons: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000")
    .then(res => this.pokemons = res.data)
    .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
  }
}
</script>

<style>
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```

PokeItem.js

```html
<template>
    <div>
      <router-link :to="pokemonLink">
        {{pokemon.name}}
      </router-link>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {}
    },
    props: {
        pokemon: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    computed: {
        pokemonLink() {
            return `/pokemon/${this.pokemon.national_id}`
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

PokeProfile.js

```html
<template>
    <h1>Hello Pokemon</h1>
</template>
<script>
export default {
}
</script>
```

The problem here is I can not move to PokeProfile.js when I click on an item in the PokeItem.js file. What could be the problem? I've checked the section of the code related to routing but I didn't see any problem.

Comment: the edits were to allow stack overflow to properly highlight the code in the question.  It is useful to have syntax properly highlighted so that people can understand what is happening at a glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue-Router uses a dynamic component (`<router-view>`) to render the components of your routes. Usually you will find this component in the template of your `app.vue`. Since you have no `<router-view>` component Vue-Router does not know where to render your route components.

### Try this:

```
// main.js

import Home from './components/Home.vue'

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: '/', component: Home},
    {path: '/pokemon/:id', component: PokeProfile},
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})
```

---

```
// components/Home.vue

// your old App.vue
```

---

```
// ./App.vue
<template>
  <main>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </main>
</template>
```